# Definition of a random sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

The following is a passage from Durrett's book on probability.

''If $X_n \in \{0,1\}$ are independent with $P(X_n=1)=a_n \to 0$ and $\sum a_n = \infty$, then $X_n \to 0$ in probability, but if we let $N(n)=\text{inf}\{m\geq n: X_m=1\}$, then $X_{N(n)}=1$ a.s.''

The statement itself is not important, but I'm having trouble understanding the sequence $X_{N(n)}$ in a rigorous way. Can someone explain how the random variables $\{X_{N(n)}\}$ look like as measurable functions and also as a subsequence of the original sequence $\{X_n\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all complicated in the beginning. I personally feel that it is much easier to understand it in terms of measure theory.

Recall that $X_n$ is just a measurable function on some probability space (about which we usually don't care). But let us fix this probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}).$ So $X_n:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})\to \{0, 1\}$ is a measurable function with some properties (but I will ignore them as you said the exact statement is not important).

Now if you have another measurable function $N:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})\to \mathbb{N},$ then you can define a compostie function say $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})\to \{0, 1\}$ by $Y(\omega)=X_{N(\omega)}(\omega).$ This is what we are talking about.

Probabilistically, think of the situation as follows: Think of $X_n$ as being representing head/tail in a coin toss. But let us say you are interested in some particular $X_n,$ for example, you might be interested in what happens in the $10$th toss, that is, you are interested in $X_{10}.$ This is simple. But you might be interested in something more complicated. Imagine that you are playing a game where you win if you see $5$ consecutive zeroes and then $1.$ Naturally, if you look at the time of your first win, it is a random time, you can call it $N.$

So fundamentally, at the level of measure theory, we are just talking about the composition of measurable functions. In terms of probability, we have a sequence but we are now chosing one of the term in the sequence randomly.